# Downloading .csv from Express backend to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, csv, express

I have seen this same question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894009/getting-downloads-to-work-between-angularjs-and-express-js), however the solution is not working in my case and inputting the code snipped that was used

```
$('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ ('post') +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
           .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

returns an error that `Reference $ is not defined`

I have a download request that looks like this:

controller.js

```
$http.put('/download' {file:$scope.inputInfo.name.$modelValue+'.csv'}).success(function(data,status,headers){
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);

    })
```

app.js

```
app.put('/download', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.file)
    res.download(__dirname +'/'+ 'req.body.file, function(err){
      if(err){console.log(err)}
   })
```

})

My controller.js is returning the raw file output as data and not initiating the download from the page.  Is there something I am missing to initiate this file download in angular?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Reference $ is not defined` means it can't find jQuery at the time of execution. Is that your only error?

Comment: Yes thats my only error - when I add the jQuery library to my page I just get a blank page returned when I trigger the download

Comment: the answer that you're getting help from has an action in it's form. Actions redirect when forms are submitted. in your click handler for the submit button, you must pass `e` to the handler's callback function and use the `e.preventDefault()` method inside your callback.

Comment: This totally helped although I did not need the e.preventDefault(), I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1842294/seth) you totally set me in the right direction with the lack of jQuery on my page.

Here is my finished code that I added to controllers.js in place of the $http.put():

```
$('<form action="'+ "/download" +'" method="'+ ('post') +'">'+'<input type="hidden" name="file" value="'+$scope.inputInfo.name.$modelValue+'"'+'/></form>')
           .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Awesome that you figured it out... Glad to help!